# Apache2 SSL websites keep redirecting to the default website

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost

so I have a Apache2 web server fully operational running in ubuntu. I have successfully modified the vhosts file for normal :80 requests and all web sites function correctly. However, once I attempted to configure the vhosts for SSL, all my sites when provided with a www reroute to the default (first) site in the file. For example, the first https site is www.thepeepinghole.tk. If I enter in https://www.geekychicgirls.tk it reroutes to www.thepeepinghole.tk. What's interesting though is that if I enter https://geekychicgirls.tk it goes to the correct website. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it, I've been stuck on this for days. Thanks so much!

default-ssl:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@nixcraft.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/thepeepinghole"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /ssl/14252798.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /ssl/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /ssl/New-PositiveSSL-bundle-12.ca-bundle
    ServerName thepeepinghole.tk:443
    ServerAlias www.thepeepinghole.tk
    ErrorLog "/var/www/thepeepinghole/log/error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/thepeepinghole/log/access.log" common
    <Directory /var/www/thepeepinghole>
                DirectoryIndex index.html
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@nixcraft.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/geekychicgirls"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /ssl/14252798.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /ssl/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /ssl/New-PositiveSSL-bundle-12.ca-bundle
    ServerName geekychicgirls.tk:443
    ServerAlias www.geekychicgirls.tk
    ErrorLog "/var/www/geekychicgirls/log/error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/geekychicgirls/log/access.log" common
    <Directory /var/www/geekychicgirls>
                DirectoryIndex index.html
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Output of apache2ctl -S:

```
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
[Fri Mar 21 23:14:49 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server thepeepinghole.tk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-ssl:5)
         port 443 namevhost thepeepinghole.tk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-ssl:5)
         port 443 namevhost geekychicgirls.tk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-ssl:24)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.bondsolutionsnj.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:4)
         port 80 namevhost www.bondsolutionsnj.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:4)
         port 80 namevhost www.accessorizewithstylenj.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:22)
         port 80 namevhost www.futureretrogaming.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:38)
         port 80 namevhost www.k9minecraft.tk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:56)
         port 80 namevhost www.k9proxy.tk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:72)
         port 80 namevhost www.thepeepinghole.tk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:89)
         port 80 namevhost www.geekychicgirls.tk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:105)
Syntax OK
```

Warning on Apache2 Startup:

```
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
[Sat Mar 22 20:18:04 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
```

Comment: The port number does not belong on the ServerAlias lines.  I think you're hitting the default because they're not matching the alias due to the port being there.  [ServerAlias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias)

Comment: agree, :port in ServerName is optional but it's not an option for ServerAlias http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias

Comment: Ok I have removed the port from the file, restarted the service and still redirecting. I left the server on if you want to try for yourself. The output of the apache2ctl -S is the same as before. Although I got a new error, if you could check it out I've updated my question.

Comment: Could you update the config in the question with what you are currently using?

Comment: @Ladadadada it has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the solution was pretty simple for me (just took forever to figure out) :)

Okay so what I did was made the

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName: www.mysitehere.com
ServerAlias: mysitehere.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I also got rid of the if statement.